# VBA Filter function

Tags: vba, filter

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Dim Found() As Variant
Dim Found1 As Variant

Found = Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF((ID=""" & sString1 & """)*(No=Value(""" & sString2 & """)),ROW(ID),""z"")"))

Found1 = Filter(Found, "z", False)
```

I have a good "Found" array filled with all "z":s and just one valid hit. But when I try to use the Filter function to rid the "z" out, I get a "mismatch" error?. Why?"

ID  and No are "named ranges"
ID is strings and No is numbers

Comment: How do you declare `Found1`?

Comment: Sorry its a Variant that too. I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is where I am right now

```
Dim Found() As Variant

        Found = Application.Evaluate("=IF((ID=""" & sString1 & """)*(No=Value(""" & sString2 & """)),ROW(ID),""z"")")

        i = 1
        While Found(i, 1) = "z"
            i = i + 1
        Wend
```

If I cannot use Filter then there is no need to transpose either, I just iterate through the array till I find my match. I will always have just one! I will have up to 5000 rows to go through so timings will differ from case to case.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want an array of variants you just want a variant which happens to be an array.

```
Dim Found() As Variant
Dim Found1 As Variant

Found = Application.Transpose([A1:A5])

Found1 = Filter(Found, "z", False)
```

Comment: Correct! Tried it! but it still gives me a Type mismatch!

Comment: On which line? What is the shape of the range returned by the `Evaluate` function?

Comment: It is the Filter function that I struggle with. The Found array is a one dimensional array, filled with "z" :s where there is no match, and the row value in the ID range where there is a match. The array returned after the Evaluate function is two dimensional, but the Transpose function turns that into an one dimensional array.

Comment: You're expecting Transpose to do something different than it is doing. It doesn't take a 2D array and turn it into a 1D array. It will switch the row/column coordinates for each member in the array, just like Paste Special > Transpose. By passing a multidimensional array to Filter (which is a member of the `Strings` class) you are [violating it's expectations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fat7fw0s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). `Required. One-dimensional array of strings to be searched.`

Comment: If the ultimate question is "how do I get a list of the cell addresses/values which are not 'z'?" then there are different approaches.

Comment: OK I see. NB After the transpose is looks one-dimensional. The ultimate question is how do I find the row(s) in a sheet where the two criteria are fullfilled? In my case I know that there is only one such row, but how do I find it?